# Apache rewrite rule for a whole directory

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to rewrite a directory to its own sub folder. I have an .htaccess file in the directory, and I also put the AllowOverride All in the Apache conf file.

Basically, I want the server to redirect this url: http://example.com/MPOS to http://example.com/MPOS/public. The closest I got was using this:

```
RewriteRule /MPOS$ /MPOS/public/ [L]
```

It does the job, going to http://example.com/MPOS/public, but its the rest of the resources (all the pages, stylesheets and the rest) are not being redirected, and so I get the page as if the links are broken. Inside public folder there is "index.php" file.

I know there are many questions about it, but after hours of search nothing helped me, so I posted this question.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks,
Shay

Answer (score 0):

OK, I feel a bit stupid. Managed to get it to work by writing the rewrite like this:

```
RewriteRule ^$ /MPOS/public/ [L,R]
```

When the .htaccess is found in the "MPOS" folder.